# Wrong position of my rectangle - javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d

I have to code a dice game, but i have a problem with my dice.

So, this is my code :

```
export class Dice {

    constructor() {
        this.canvas_dice = document.getElementById("dice-canvas");
    }

    drawDice(value) {
        let ctx = this.canvas_dice.getContext('2d');
        let canvas_size = this.canvas_dice.width;
        let dot_size = canvas_size / 3;
        let matrice = {
            1: [[1, 1]],
            2: [[0, 0], [2, 2]],
            3: [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]],
            4: [[0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2], [2, 2]],
            5: [[0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2], [2, 2], [1, 1]],
            6: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
        }

        matrice[value].forEach(dot => {
            console.log(dot);
            let x = dot[0] * dot_size;
            let y = dot[1] * dot_size;

            console.log(x + " " + y);

            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, dot_size, dot_size);
        });
    }
}
```

And for example, when I call the function like this

```
let dice = new Dice();
dice.drawDice(2);
```

I have [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwwXc.png) on my browser and [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G71iW.png) in my console.

I don't understand why my dot isn't in the good position.

And I have the same issue with every other value in my drawDice function.

Can you see my mistake and how could I fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the height of the canvas element. Your dots are being cut off.

By default a canvas elements height is set at 150px. The width is set at 300px. Just needed to make the canvas element a square to create your die face.
[HTMLCanvasElement.height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height)

Adding the following line in the drawDice function seems to fix this problem.

```
        this.canvas_dice.height = canvas_size;
```

Comment: Just a note - the way things are currently implemented, the 6 would appear as 2 solid columns.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked !
I thought the size of the canvas was already scaled to the html element.

For the 6, I knew it. This is just the beginning of my code, in order to display the points. I'll refine the rest later. 

Have a nice day !